# Error 0x81030120 on windows phone 8 app deployment

Tags: windows-8

I have built a windows phone 8 app using visual studio 2012. I was able to run apps previously but now i get the error: 0x81030120. I have read in several post that i need to remove this line

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_INTEROPSERVICES" />
```

from WMAppManifest file. but once i do so i get this error:

> Installation of the application failed. Run time error has occurred.
>   Fix the Capabilities in WMAppManifest.xml file.

I tried the solution

Someone help.

Comment: You need to unlock your device.  Described pretty well in [this web page](http://www.xda-developers.com/windows_phone/interop-unlock-for-samsung-windows-phone-8-devices/)

Comment: Well my phone is already unlocked, i solved the problem by starting the application again from scratch